# Updating website with Mupx without deleting MongoDB on host server

Tags: meteor

I deployed my website with Mupx into DigitalOcean servers several days ago. I have several updates I want to make without deleting the MongoDB on the DigitalOcean servers (don't want user accounts to be overwritten).

Now, to update my app on my DigitalOcean servers while keeping the DigitalOcean database untouched, is it as simple as changing `"setupMongo"` to `false` in the mup.json file? Just want to make sure I'm doing this correctly without messing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well if i am not wrong you ran 
`mup setup` to setup the server and might had the url as

`mongodb://localhost:2701/your_db_Name`

and you deployed with `mup deploy` you can run mup deploy again and make changes to your app without having reseting the users.. if you want to change the mongo URL then you have to migrate your previous Data into new db

Comment: I ran `mup setup`, then `mup deploy`. Now if I do `mup deploy` again without `mup setup`, the database on DigitalOcean will not be affected?

Comment: no it wont be affected infact it will use same database and all works same as before..

Comment: But if I don't run `mup setup`, then how can the changes that I made be updated with just `mup deploy`?

Comment: what it does is bundle the app, upload to server,  cd into the app dir `opt/yourAppName` and run the app  with the environmental variable that you have provided so what its doing is updating the app new version thats all...